# jOOQ - multi-field for insertion

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I would like to express the following `INSERT` statement:

```
context.insertInto(TABLE A)
   .set(<FIELD A, FIELD B>, context.select(FIELD A, FIELD B).from(B).where(...))
   .set(... other field of table A ...)
   .set(... other field of table A ...)
   .set(... other field of table A ...)
   .returning()
   .fetch()
```

The sub-select returns one row with two columns (`FIELD A` and `FIELD B`) which need to be inserted into the target `TABLE A`. The reason for this is that `<FIELD A, FIELD B>` is the primary key of `TABLE B`. `TABLE A` is refering to `TABLE B` (foreign key).

Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting, in what database is this possible?

Comment: Good question :). This happens if you are only using jOOQ, and expecting jOOQ to be able to translate everything. This is indeed not possible in plain SQL.

Comment: This gives me a good reason to finally refactor these composite primary keys into single primary keys. I can use `DSL.field(... select ...)` afterwards and just insert this `select field` as a plain field, if I am not mistaken. In that way, I just have a set of fields, which makes the code much easier.

Comment: *"This happens if you are only using jOOQ, and expecting jOOQ to be able to translate everything"* I thought so - too powerful :) Although, in this case, I think that transformation would be rather difficult... Yes, with a single PK field, you could do this with the `INSERT .. VALUES` (or jOOQ's equivalent `INSERT .. SET`) syntax - although composite primary keys can be useful too, for performance reasons (see: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html)

Comment: Interesting read, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible with any SQL dialect in the first place, via `INSERT .. VALUES`, but you can certainly express that sort of query using `INSERT .. SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO a (a, b, x, y, z)
SELECT a, b, ... other value ..., ... other value ..., ... other value ...
FROM b
WHERE ...
RETURNING *;
```

Or with jOOQ

```java
context.insertInto(TABLE A, ... columns ...)
       .select(
           select(
               FIELD A, 
               FIELD B,
               ... other field of table A ...,
               ... other field of table A ...,
               ... other field of table A ...)
          .from(B)
          .where(...))
       )
       .returning()
       .fetch()
```

Comment: Hi Lukas. The `returning` function does not seem to be available after a `select`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028601/jooq-insert-into-select-returning.

Comment: @KevinDeGrote: You're right. Thanks for pointing this out. This will be [fixed in jOOQ 3.7 via #3779](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3779), which is why I'm leaving this answer as it is.