# jOOQ - INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... RETURNING

Tags: postgresql, jooq

Is it possible to create a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... RETURNING` statement with jOOQ? If so, how?

There is no `returning` function here:

```
context.insertInto(table, list of fields).select(select statement).returning()
```

If this is indeed absent, is there a smart workaround available? I cannot express my `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` as a `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...`. See question [jOOQ - multi-field for insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959180/jooq-multi-field-for-insertion) for more details about the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That combination of `INSERT` keywords was indeed not possible until jOOQ 3.7 via [#3779](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3779).

A workaround in the meantime would be to use plain SQL:

```
Result<Record> result = context.fetch("{0} returning *", insertInto(...).select(...));
```

Comment: Hi Lukas. This works fine. However, I suspect that my `org.jooq.Converter`'s (from `Timestamp` to `LocalDateTime` in my case) are not being called anymore with this approach. Any extra workaround necessary for this? (Should I open a new question for this?)

Comment: @KevinDeGrote: I see, Unfortunately, I currently don't see any workarounds, short of going deep into the internals of jOOQ. One workaround would be to form a CTE for the `INSERT` statement, but this currently cannot be done with plain SQL. (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4474). What we'd need is a way to set the `<R>` type on the `ResultQuery` prior to actually executing it. I've registered a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4473. Thanks for the heads-up!